# Exclude tests in pytest configuration file

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to be able to *exclude* instead of *include* certain python test files in the `pytest.ini` configuration file. According to the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/pythoncollection.html#ignore-paths-during-test-collection) including tests boils down to something like this:

```
# content of pytest.ini
[pytest]
pytest_files=test_main.py test_common.py
```

To exclude files however, only command line options are suggested:

`--ignore=test_common.py`

How can I actually select files to *ignore* at the `pytest.ini` file level?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add any command line options in `pytest.ini` under [`addopts`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#confval-addopts). In your case this should work:

*pytest.ini*

```
[pytest]
addopts = --ignore=test_common.py
```

As has been noted in the comments, `--ignore` takes a path (relative or absolute), not just a module name. From the output of `pytest -h`:

```
  --ignore=path         ignore path during collection (multi-allowed).
  --ignore-glob=path    ignore path pattern during collection (multi-allowed).
```